# Power Apps Fulltext search in LookUp column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Because my SharePoint list has more than 5000 items and there is a problem with searching (after indexed columns, SharePoint `search` input show nothing). I'm trying to create a PowerApp for search in this sheet.

One of the column in the SharePoint List is `LookUp`, and items are stored in another List. This code below works good in my Power Apps search input `txtSearch`

```
With(
    {itemDoda: txtSearch.Text},
        Filter(
        'ListA',
        'ListAColumnName'.Value = itemDoda
    )
)
```

But, is it possible to change this code to search in fulltext?

When I have item in the list `roses are red` and in `txtSearch` put only `roses` found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With(
    {itemDoda: txtSearch.Text},
        Filter(
        'ListA',
        itemDoda in 'ListAColumnName'.Value
    )
)
```

**OR** simply:

```
Filter(
    'ListA',
    IsBlankOrError(txtSearch.Text) || txtSearch.Text in 'ListAColumnName'.Value
)
```

Comment: ````in```` makes Delegation Warrning, not work correctly in large data sets.

Comment: How many items are in `ListA`? Also, `in` is not delegable function with SharePoint. But it fits for your requirements to search for full text.

Comment: ListA contains 5000+ items, thats why ````IN```` i cant use.

Comment: Oh ok. IN operator is not delegable so you cannot use full text search using it. However, `StartsWith` is delegable in SharePoint if you want to use it instead of IN operator. Check if it helps: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Delegation-warning-with-quot-IN-quot-operator-on-a-sharepoint/td-p/630165

Comment: when i put all items to Collections, for example 1000 items per 1 Collection and merge them. ````IN```` works. Thank you so much.